# understanding hash references

Tags: perl, hash, reference

I am fairly new to perl and I am having a hard time understanding hash references and I am slightly stuck on a certain concept/question:

What code could I use to set the variable $red equal to the value at key $color in the hash reference $hash?

This is just a simpler version of a more complex question. 
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is fairly straightforward. You access an element in a hash reference by using curly braces `{}` to tell Perl you want a hash element, and the arrow operator `->` to tell it to dereference. The [*sigil*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigil_(computer_programming)) is a dollar sign `$` because the value you get back is [*scalar*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_(computer_science)), which means it is a single atomic value.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $hash = {
    red   => 'ff0000',
    green => '00ff00',
    blue  => '0000ff',
};

my $color = 'red';
my $red   = $hash->{$color};

print $red;
```

This prints

```
ff0000
```

You should take a look at [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html), [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) and [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) in perldoc.

Comment: I think in that case the sigil is `$` because `$hash` is a scalar. if you had used `${$hash}{$color}` then the *second* dollar is because the result is a scalar.

Comment: @Borodin in your case the _first_ dollar is for the scalar result. The second one inside the first curlies is because `$hash` is a scalar. But to be honest that's a bit too complicated for what the question is asking and the perceived level of the OP. I believe in teaching one way first, so they can get started.

Comment: Yes, when I said "second" I meant "additional", or in fact the first one!

Comment: @Borodin do you have an idea for a talk I could give at the German Perl Workshop and/or YAPC::EU? I can't come up with anything.

Comment: I could come up with a few things, but I'd be guessing about whether they're a fit with your likes and abilities, and the events themselves. Why don't you look back through the [*Perl Weekly* archive](http://perlweekly.com/archive/) for inspiration?

Comment: Remember to link me to any videos.

Comment: Incidentally, *straightforward* is an unhyphenated, although unlikely, English word :)

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully you know how to access an *ordinary* hash, like

```
my %data = ( red => 'a', blue => 'b', green => 'c' );
```

There's no need for quotes around the colour names because the "fat comma" `=>` does that for us

(I dislike `%hash` as a name for a hash, because the `%` tells us that it's a hash.)

Let's set

```
my $color = 'blue';
```

Now, you can access the `blue` element of the hash with

```
$data{$color}
```

The initial dollar `$` is there because the result of accessing a single hash element is a *scalar*, and Perl scalars start with a dollar. The value of this expression is the string `b`

You may also write this as

```
${data}{$color}
```

which has exactly the same result. This may not seem very useful, but bear with me: it will be a good *aide-memoire*

Now, we can set a (scalar) variable `$hash` to be a reference to our hash `%data`

```
my $hash = \%data;
```

and we can access the same element as before by replacing the *name* of the hash `data` by the variable containing the reference. So

```
${data}{$color}
```

is now the same as

```
${$hash}{$color}
```

It's also the same as

```
$$hash{$color}
```

but now that we're dealing with a data reference, it's far less obvious what that means. You can stick with `${$hash}{$color}` or you can use the newer *arrow operator* and write

```
$hash->{$color}
```

which is the generally recommended and least ambiguous syntax

Now, your question was (paraphrased)

> How can I set the variable `$red` equal to the value in the hash referred to by `$hash` with a key of `$color`?

While it's horribly confusing to use `$red` as the variable name, I'll go with it!

You want

```
my $red = $hash->{$color}
```

With the above values, `$red` will now contain the string `b`. If you're happy with that then read no further

The same assignmment can be made

```
my $red = ${$hash}{$color}
```

or, worse

```
my $red = $$hash{$color}
```

and you may well see these in older (or new, badly-written) code

I hope that helps?

Comment: But in fairness - `%data` is scarcely more descriptive than `%hash` :)

Comment: @Sobrique: It's the best I could do without knowing what this stuff is. In fact it's probably an abstract invention.